DataDog integration with EMR Serverless
Does anyone know how to integrate DataDog with EMR Serverless? Any documentation will really be helpful.

As of July 2024, there is no direct integration. However you can monitor it through a CloudWatch Metric + CloudWatch Alarm.
Something like (if you use AWS CDK with Python):
aws_cloudwatch.Alarm(
    metric=aws_cloudwatch.Metric(
        metric_name="FailedJobs",
        namespace="AWS/EMRServerless",
        dimensions_map={"ApplicationId": <serverless_emr_app_id>},
        period=aws_cdk.Duration.minutes(1),
        statistic="sum",
    ),
    evaluation_periods=1,
    threshold=0,
    comparison_operator=aws_cloudwatch.ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_THRESHOLD,
    datapoints_to_alarm=1,
    ...,
)

And with that Alarm your possibilities are countless.
